# How to test a function in var in javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs

Given a piece of code like below, which is adopted from [reinforcejs](https://github.com/karpathy/reinforcejs/blob/master/lib/rl.js)

```
var RL = {};
(function(global) {
    var sampleWeighted = function(p) {
        var r = Math.random();
        var c = 0.0;            // cumulative prob
        for(var i=0, n=p.length; i<n; i++) {
            c += p[i];
            if (c >= r) { return i; }
        }
        // assert(false) may happen if sum(p) < 1;
        assert(false, 'wtf');
    };

// many content omitted
...
})(RL);

export default RL;
```

How can I access sampleWeighted and test it, please? I have tried below

```
import RL from './rl.js';

it('sampleWeighted', () => {
    expect(RL.sampleWeighted([0.5, 0.5])).toEqual(1);
});
```

But it complains with error

```
 FAIL  src/lib/rl.test.js
  ✕ sampleWeighted (1ms)

  ● sampleWeighted

    TypeError: _rl.RL.sampleWeighted is not a function

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/rl.test.js:7:46)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

I am new to javascript testing. Currently, I am using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to setup the testing framework. So what's the proper way to test the above function, please? If you happened to understand what `sampleWeighted` does, please feel free to comment on it, too.

Comment: Instead of `var sampleWeighted`, try `global.sampleWeighted`

Comment: Do you mean the code was written in a way that's untestable? I tried to follow the original author's convention if possible.

Comment: Sort of. `sampleWeighted` is a private function inside `IIFE`. Code inside it can use it but will not be available to outside code.

Comment: I suspect there's perhaps some code in the lines you omitted that are important, specifically where `sampleWeighted` is attached to the RL object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sampleWeighted is in the closure of your `IIFE` (Immediate function invocation syntax)

this way you could keep your method private like `private public` in Java, notice you have pass the global which is RL, you can treat that as your namespace, and if you want to call sampleWeighted, you need to attach sampleWeighted to `RL`,

```
...
RL.sampleWeighted = function() {}
...
```

Comment: Its `IIFE` (Immediately Invoked Function Execution) and its not closure, its scope

Comment: @Rajesh, Can you confirm the way it's written in `var sampleWeighted` is untestable? Further, does it mean we shouldn't write code like this at all if it needs tested?

Comment: What if I want to call `sampleWeighted` in another part of the code inside `(function(global) {......}`, how should it be called? `global.sampleWeight` looks quite verbose, yes?

Comment: @Rajesh isn't IIFE accomplished via clousure?  when a function executed inside another function and use the variable from the enclosed function, it is a clousure

Comment: @Sean not necessary. If you see OP's code, its an IIFE not wrapped in function. So I assume its used to prevent polluting global scope.

Comment: @zyxue You can refer following [sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/quvxnx2z/1/) of function as class in JS. This might help

Comment: of cause it is used to prevent polluting global scope, we use `clousure` to encapsulate private method to not visitable from outside

Comment: @Rajesh, is the function `notify` in your fiddle testable, please?

Comment: It is only testable through `notifyOne` and `notifyTwo` but not on its own

Comment: @zyxue, I notice you are using es6 export syntax, are you using babel to compile your code? if so, you can just use commonjs pattern. and for the perspective of test code,  you should **only** test public code.

Comment: Yes, I am writing es6, and using babel.

Answer (score 1):

Write code inside a closure that gives our test code access to the private functions we care about, but then remove that code when we deploy to production.
here you can write your code exactly how you’d like it to appear when released, then add on whatever bridge code you need to expose the parts you want to test.

**If you’re using a build system, you can do exactly that.**

```
var RL = {};
(function(global) {
    var sampleWeighted = function(p) {
        var r = Math.random();
        var c = 0.0;            // cumulative prob
        for(var i=0, n=p.length; i<n; i++) {
            c += p[i];
            if (c >= r) { return i; }
        }
        // assert(false) may happen if sum(p) < 1;
        assert(false, 'wtf');
    };

    var api = {
        bar: function() {
            // public function `bar` returned from closure
            return "bar"
        }
    };

    /* test-code */
        api._foo = foo
    /* end-test-code */

    return api    

})(RL);

export default RL;
```

and then you can use  "grunt-strip-code"

```
npm install grunt-strip-code --save-dev
```

Then enable it inside your Gruntfile:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-strip-code');


grunt.initConfig({
  strip_code: {
    options: {
      start_comment: "test-code",
      end_comment: "end-test-code",
    },
    your_target: {
      // a list of files you want to strip code from
      src: "dist/*.js"
    }
  }
})


grunt.registerTask("test", [
  "concat",
  "jshint",
  "jasmine"
])
grunt.registerTask("deploy", [
  "concat",
  "strip-code",
  "jshint",
  "uglify"
])
```

Rerefence - https://philipwalton.com/articles/how-to-unit-test-private-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: that doesn't work, you have to attach your api to the global object. you cannot just return api.

Comment: grunt-strip-code looks a bit hackish, is it a best practice to do so?

Answer (score 1):

In your IIFE you have not attached `sampleWeighted` to the passed in object (global). So make sure you do something like below inside of your IIFE:

```
global.sampleWeighted = sampleWeighted;
```

Also, in your test file, you need to access that function using:

```
RL.sampleWeighted
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's working. I have this impression that this IIFE way is phasing out with ES6's module system (e.g. [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), is that right?

Comment: In a way, for some uses...but IIFE is also used if you want to execute a function as soon as the script is parsed, which I'm not sure is something that ES6 modules are designed for.